# How Kuratowski representation of ordered paris produce different set than Hausdorff representation of ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While defining Cartesian products I came across the kuratowski representation of ordered pair of two elements $(a,b)$ as: $$\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$$ and a slight modification of Hausdorff definition of ordered pair of two elements $(a,b)$ as: $$\{\{a,\varnothing\},\{b,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$$

It was stated that they do not form equal sets but not stated how.

All of this is in reference to ZFC set theory.

Comment: Consider the pair $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$. The Kuratowski set corresponding to it is $\{\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\varnothing\}\}= \{\{\varnothing\}\}$. The Hausdoff set corresponding to it $\{\{\varnothing,\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\} = \{\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$. So the Kuratowski set has one element, the Hausdorff set has two.

Comment: Well, they certainly don't look equal.  It would be more surprising if they were equal than if they weren't.